# Hosting a ASP.NET MVC Application my server a lot of errors

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, connection-string, localdb

I'm going to try to be so detailed as possible. Please if you need more info please ask. So 3 days ago i finished a website it was ready for a small alpha test. But when i uploaded it to my server with IIS 8.5.6900.16384. I'm quite new to MVC and ASP.NET. And have never hosted a website. So i'm trying to fugue out how it works.

So i when to sites and created a new website. : 
Application Pool = DefuaultAppPool
Puted a physical path of : K:\www\Init
Site name InitWebsite.
The website Had 2 databases I only cared about 1 Its name is ASPNET-InitSquad-20170512014420.mdf.

When i stated the website i got a sql error 52. That it could not connect to the server. Why i still dont know but i got it working a few hours later. But i got a other message Error 50. I also dont have the specifics anymore. But all i can remeber is that i installed a lot of SQL software. I installed:

```
SQL Express 2012
SQL Express 2014
SQL Express 2016 (I first could not install this but got it working)
SQL LocalDB 2012 Version 11
SQL LocalDB 2014 Version 12
SQL LocalDB 2016 Version 13.0.4001
I have also installed 
SSMS V17
```

After a full 12 hours of installing i finally finished. Than i got error 26. Again i dont have that info anymore. That was yesterday That is when i decided to call quites for the night. So after all that i have tryed all thease connection strings :

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=KEVIN-SERVER\SQLEXPRESS01;AttachDbFilename=K:\www\InitSquad.com\App_Data\aspnet-InitSquad-20170512024420.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-InitSquad-20170512024420;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-InitSquad-20170512024420.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-InitSquad-20170512024420;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

<connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v13;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-InitSquad-20170512024420.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-InitSquad-20170512024420;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>

<connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=KEVIN-SERVER\SQLEXPRESS01;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-InitSquad-20170512024420.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-InitSquad-20170512024420;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
```

After a lot of testing non of these worked. Again a dead end. Now a few hours ago i was reading more i got a error again. Error 50 With a code (0x80131904) I don't exactly remember the phrase but i can recreate it if its needed. Now its the same and its saying Database"DatabasePath" Already Exists. Choose a different database name. Cannot attach the file "DatabasePath" As Database "DatabaseName"
That is where i'm now i was searching i have unblocked some ports.

And it still doesn't work. Than i was reading that i soul get SQL Server Agent (MSSQLLOCALDB) To run but i tried it but i seem not to be able to get it working its saying it takes too long to start. And yes i have opened the ports. Just to get the start button to enable was already a pain. Anyone got suggestions. This is almost impossible to do at this point i'm going in to the 5th day now. Please just tell me if you need any more info. I am also using Visual Studio 2017. A other person is saying you need to pay for it. What sounds a bit weird that Microsoft is going to force people to pay for web applications  with databases. So in basic terms everything on the internet

Answer (score 0):

I got it It was the connection string i was awake for 4 days just because of the connection string. Tip for new users don't take LocalDB create a new DB sql will do this for you this was my end connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=KEVIN-SERVER\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=ASPNETAplicationDatabase;Trusted_Connection=yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

This video is the best https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwckH9bVqPc

Comment: Well done for sticking with it, Two tips: 1, Always record the error message. No one can troubleshoot without a problem description. 2. YOU may wish to consider using Azure or AWS. YOu can run up a web server and SQL Server in ten minutes and you don't need to install anything.